# Finding mass by integration

Tags: calculus

I need some help here:

> Find the mass of a straight wire of length $L$ [cm] with density
>    $Q(s) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{L}\right)$ at distance $s$ [cm] from one end.

What I did was to integrate from $0$ to $L \sin(\pi s)/L$ ds, which apparently is wrong. Could anyone help?

What's wrong?

Comment: Is the density $\sin (\pi \frac{s}{L})$?

Comment: That gives the right answer, so I guesss so. =) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The integration you are carrying out will give the mass of the wire as

$$\frac{1-\cos(\pi L)}{\pi L}$$

What appears to you to be wrong would be that on putting $L=2$, we get the mass $0$. But then the density function itself was negative for half a cycle. (Check it with $L=2$ and $s=3/2$)